# If $H$ Hilbert space, $T\in L(H)$, $(z_{n})\subset H$ orthonormal, $y\in T(H)$. Show under some conditions that $\sum|\langle y,z_{n}\rangle|<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space , $T\in L(H)$ (set of all continuous linear functions of $H$ in $H$), $(z_{n})$ a othonormal sequence on $H$, and $(\lambda_{n})$ a sequence in $\mathbb{K}$  (it is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) such that $T^{*}(z_{n})=\lambda_{n}z_{n}$  (where $T^{*}$ is the adjoint map of $T$) and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_{n}|^{2}<\infty$.

Show that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\langle y,z_{n}\rangle\right|<\infty$$
for all $y\in T(H)$.

**Remark:** I am distrusting the hypothesis $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_{n}|^{2}<\infty$. Note that if we replace $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_{n}|^{2}<\infty$ for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_{n}|<\infty$ then the problem is easier to show, in fact, for $y=T(x)\in T(H)$ we would have 
$$|\langle y,z_{n}\rangle|=|\langle T(x),z_{n}\rangle|=|\langle x,T^{*}(z_{n})\rangle|=|\langle x,\lambda_{n}z_{n}\rangle|\leq|\lambda_{n}|\|x\|.$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle y,z_{n}\rangle|\leq \|x\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_{n}|<\infty.$$
**I do not see how to prove it if the hypothesis is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\lambda_{n}|^{2}<\infty$.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\lvert\langle y, z_n\rangle\rvert = \lvert \lambda_n\rvert\cdot \lvert \langle x,z_n\rangle\rvert,$$

and by Bessel's inequality

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lvert \langle x,z_n\rangle\rvert^2 \leqslant \lVert x\rVert^2.$$

And by Cauchy-Schwarz

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lvert \lambda_n\rvert\cdot \lvert \langle x,z_n\rangle\rvert \leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lvert \lambda_n\rvert^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lvert \langle x, z_n\rangle\rvert^2}\,.$$